# data retrieve from SQLite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a table name "thanas" with thana_name,mobile_no,telephone_no,district_name column in SQLite database. Data is also inserted now i want to retrieve 3 column data that matches district_name. but in LogCat only first column data shows . I also tried to make a ArrayAdapter with this data to shows it in ListView . In listview only thana_name shows. I called populateArrayListOfDhakaDistrict () this method inside onCreat() method. all thing is right but it shows only first column.

```
public static final String SELECT_THANA_NAME_MOBILE_TELIPHONE = "select thana_name, mobile_no, telephone_no from thanas where thanas.district_name like '%Dhaka%' ;";

    public Cursor getThanaInfo() {
             return db.rawQuery(SELECT_THANA_NAME_MOBILE_TELIPHONE, null);
         }


    public void populateArrayListOfDhakaDistrict () {
            List <String> thanaInfoList = getAllThanaInfo();


            System.out.println("unsorted: "+thanaInfoList);
            ListView listView = getListView();

            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            //listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);      
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,thanaInfoList);     
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

        public List <String> getAllThanaInfo() {
            dbOperation.open();
            //List <String> devisionInfoList = new ArrayList<String> ();
            Cursor c= dbOperation.getThanaInfo();
            c.moveToFirst();
            while (! c.isAfterLast()) {
                String thanaInfo= new String(c.getString(0));
                //String teleInfo = new String (c.getColumnIndex(thanaInfo));
                thanaInfoList.add(thanaInfo);

                System.out.println("Thana is:"+thanaInfo);
                c.moveToNext();
            }
            c.close();
            return thanaInfoList;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c.moveToFirst();
while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
    String thanaInfo = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("thana_name"));
    thanaInfoList.add(thanaInfo);

    System.out.println("Thana is:" + thanaInfo);
    c.moveToNext();
}
c.close();
return thanaInfoList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public static final String SELECT_THANA_NAME_MOBILE_TELIPHONE = "select thana_name, mobile_no, telephone_no from thanas where thanas.district_name like '%Dhaka%' ;";
private             List <String> thanaInfoList ;


    public Cursor getThanaInfo() {
             return db.rawQuery(SELECT_THANA_NAME_MOBILE_TELIPHONE, null);
         }


    public void populateArrayListOfDhakaDistrict () {


            System.out.println("unsorted: "+thanaInfoList);
            ListView listView = getListView();

            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            //listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);      
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,thanaInfoList);     
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

        public void getAllThanaInfo() {
            dbOperation.open();
            List <String> thanaInfoList = new List<String>;
            Cursor c= dbOperation.getThanaInfo();
             if ( C != null) {
             try {
                 while (c.moveToNext()) {
                      thanaInfoList.add(c.getString(0));

                }
               } finally {
                   c.close();
    }

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

As you already know what columns are returned, you don't need `getColumnIndex`, just refer correct column index:

```
 String thanaInfo = c.getString(0);
```

Comment: yap you right. i checked it c.getString(1); this code also work . it shows second column.... thank you.